# Grammar error in "visible communities" text, in the Hidden Communities profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals, hidden-communities

A small update:  Even with the new [responsive changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369819/the-site-settings-section-of-user-preferences-is-now-fully-responsive?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C99.3685), this still hasn't been fixed and is a fairly big grammatical error.

---

In my [Hide Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) profile page, there's a grammar error down at the bottom where it says, "Showing X communities out of X communities":

[image]

Except it says "12 community" instead of "12 communities".

Comment: I think it would be better as "Showing 12 out of 156 visible communities". The text doesn't show if you have only one visible community, so we don't have to worry about "1 community" but I think it's cleaner to omit the redundant "communities".

Comment: Checking this string on [Traducir](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Showing%20%5C%24num%5C%24) (for SOpt) it's possible to see that there are 4 different strings for this (1:1, 1:n, n:1, n:n), but the original strings are all in plural-plural (n:n)

Comment: Added this issue to be addressed as part of regular bug duty rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug! There was an issue with pluralization on this specific string. The issue was just fixed.