# Pluralization bug: "[Showing] 12 community" on the "Hide Communities" page

Tags: bug, plurals, preferences, hidden-communities

There's a pluralization [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on the "[Hide Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current)" page of the Settings tab in the user profile:

[image: Screenshot of Hide Communities page, showing the text "Showing 12 community out of 23 visible communities". The word "community" has been underlined in red.]

Here, "12 community" should be "12 communit**ies**".

Comment: \[Obligatory comment about [something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/786798) deprecated with something deprecated] How hard is it to just wrap all those instances in a dedicated helper? The sheer time collectively wasted on reporting and fixing those bugs one-by-one...

Comment: Not sure, is it a dupe? [Grammar error in "visible communities" text, in the Hidden Communities profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359035/grammar-error-in-visible-communities-text-in-the-hidden-communities-profile-p)